# Nginx's upstream failed, how to recover

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

From the doc: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#server

It said when the upstream reached `max_fails` within `fail_timeout` and it will become dead. What if my server is up sometimes after?

In general,

1. If a upstream server failed, will nginx retry with another server in the pool?
2. Any variable I can configure so that they will join the pool automatically when they are up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to states that nginx will try the upstream again after `fail_timeout` seconds, to see if it has come back up.